# When i ignore the google captcha it does'nt show the error message

Tags: html, css, wordpress, recaptcha

This is my website. http://travelsweetnsour.com/2016/12/24/srinagar-kashmir-india/ In comment form i implemented google captcha using WP-reCAPTCHA-bp plugin. When i ignore the google captcha it does'nt show the error message.

Please help, Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have some problem, *always* (***always**!*) have a look in the [developer tool](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)s of your browser.

In your case, there are [some errors](https://snag.gy/DKPV80.jpg) in the capthca plugin.

Then, i found that you load captcha JS file twice: here:

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en"></script>
```

and here:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Get rid of one of them.

In your code, pass the correct ID (**id="submit-alt"**) for the submit button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var sub = document.getElementById('submit-alt');
   document.getElementById('recaptcha-submit-btn-area').appendChild (sub);
   document.getElementById('submit-alt').tabIndex = 6;
   if ( typeof _recaptcha_wordpress_savedcomment != 'undefined') {
       document.getElementById('comment').value = _recaptcha_wordpress_savedcomment;
   }
</script>
```

In fact, your submit button has this ID:

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit-alt" tabindex="6" value="Submit Comment">
```

Comment: I removed that error still not showing error message when i ignore captcha

Comment: captcha is showing , when i fill the form, i leave captcha but it should show the error message right , that will not shown here

Comment: ok, so, my advice is to read carefully the 'faq', and installation guide of the plugin! :-D

Comment: In the code i see that the JS is not updated: document.getElementById('submit').tabIndex = 6;

Comment: Finally i solved this issue. Thanks lot for your support

Comment: Good! if my asnwer solved the issue, @user7357089 mark it as it solved!

Comment: sorry your answer not solved my issue so i didn't accept. but i already given upvote

Comment: Oh, ok. :-D But, i've seen that in your code the button has the ID "submit". have you tried to replace with "submit-alt", as i mentioned in my answer? in my opinion that would fix it!